# How would you do this with lodash/underscore?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a .json which looks like this but it is actually way much bigger

```
[
  {
    "enterprise" : [
      {
        "id" : "743512",
        "name" : "Hellen Quesada",
        "role" : "P. Software Engineer",
        "picture" : "http://i276.photobucket.com/albums/kk35/Sicable/200x200/06.png",
        "skype" : "he.quesada",
        "email" : "hquesada1@publicisgroupe.net",
        "account" : "Digitas, Flag",
        "subDept" : "Enterprise",
        "location" : "Offshore: Costa Rica"
      },
      {
        "id" : "743587",
        "name" : "Jonathan Chavez",
        "role" : "P. Creative Engineer",
        "picture" : "http://i276.photobucket.com/albums/kk35/Sicable/200x200/06.png",
        "skype" : "jonathanchavesb",
        "email" : "jonathan.chaves@prodigious.cr",
        "account" : "Digitas, Flag",
        "subDept" : "Enterprise",
        "location" : "Offshore: Costa Rica"
      },
      {
        "id" : "749058",
        "name" : "Rodrigo Ovares",
        "role" : "Creative Engineer",
        "picture" : "http://i276.photobucket.com/albums/kk35/Sicable/200x200/06.png",
        "skype" : "rodrigo.ovares.arroyo",
        "email" : "rodrigo.ovares@publicisgroupe.net",
        "account" : "Digitas, Flag",
        "subDept" : "Enterprise",
        "location" : "Offshore: Costa Rica"
      },
      {
        "id" : "750684",
        "name" : "Juan Morera",
        "role" : "Software Engineer",
        "picture" : "http://i276.photobucket.com/albums/kk35/Sicable/200x200/06.png",
        "skype" : "morerajuan",
        "email" : "juan.morera@prodigious.cr",
        "account" : "Digitas, Flag",
        "subDept" : "Enterprise",
        "location" : "Offshore: Costa Rica"
      }
]
```

and I am iterating over it like this

```
$.map(JSON.parse(getData), function(items) {
    $.map(items, function(item) {
        $.map(item, function(data) {
                if (id === data.id) {
                    // SOMETHING HAPPENS HERE
                        cardTemplate.push('<li><span class="name-role" id="name">' +
                            '<span><img class="card-picture" src="'+ data.picture +'"/></span>' +
                            '<div class="main-info-card">' +
                              data.name + '<br>' +
                              data.role + '<br>' +
                              'Employee N.' + data.id +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</span></li>' +
                        '<li><p>Email: <strong>'+ data.email +'</strong></p></li>' +
                        '<li><p>Skype: <strong>'+ data.skype +'</strong></p></li>' +
                        '<li><p class="team"> '+ data.account +' <br> <strong>Enterprise</strong></p></li>' +
                        '<li><strong> '+ data.location +'</strong></li>');
                }
        });
    });
});
```

a friend just ask me to use lodash and I am reading some of the concepts like map, forEach, each, etc but I want to know how to improve the code above with less nesting, something like the _.flatten or _.deepFlatten but the problem I have is that I am not getting the concept very well.

Can you help me by giving me an example or a better solution to avoid the usage of the $.map as I am doing above.

So far it works as expected, all I need in to improve the way I am coding it.

Comment: how should the result look like?

Comment: @NinaScholz see the code I paste when I do the `id` comparison in the code.

Comment: Well for one thing don't use `map`unless you plan on using map. it seems like you just want to use an each loop here...

Comment: Why you are using `map` for iterating instead of `each`?

Comment: @isvforall JINX! ;-P

Comment: i often start with `[].map()` to dev and move to `[].forEach` at the end to improve perf and readability.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work: :-)

```
let json = JSON.parse(jsonData);

json.forEach(function (itemLists) {
   _.each(itemLists, function (items, index) {
        var filteredItems = _.where(items, {id: id});
        cartTemplate.push.apply(cartTemplate, _.map(filteredItems, function(data) {
             return '<li><span class="name-role" id="name">' +
                            '<span><img class="card-picture" src="'+ data.picture +'"/></span>' +
                            '<div class="main-info-card">' +
                              data.name + '<br>' +
                              data.role + '<br>' +
                              'Employee N.' + data.id +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</span></li>' +
                        '<li><p>Email: <strong>'+ data.email +'</strong></p></li>' +
                        '<li><p>Skype: <strong>'+ data.skype +'</strong></p></li>' +
                        '<li><p class="team"> '+ data.account +' <br> <strong>Enterprise</strong></p></li>' +
                        '<li><strong> '+ data.location +'</strong></li>';
        }));
   });
});
```

Comment: Can use `_.each(json, function ()...)` instead of `json.forEach(function()...`

Comment: yes but I am getting an error on the `_.where` function don't know why

Comment: and also you used ES6 here, I am not able to use that in my project.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer I removed the es6 stuff from the code.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: _.where is not a function`

Comment: Make sure you have underscore loaded. because it is definitely a function and I have used it many times before http://underscorejs.org/#where

Comment: I am using lodash in thos case and I don't see _.where in their docs and I am pretty sure I have saw that before too.

Comment: It seems like lodash 4 is not backwards compatible with underscore.  You may have to downgrade to lodash 3.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammeror maybe use filter with a defined filter function to look for the id.

Comment: I am doing a comparison of `id`s, everytime the user clicks on a cart, every cart has an id which I need to compare to another section and display the proper info for the current `id`. The way I have it now with jQuery works properly. I just want to use lodash so I kept the code the same way but instead of $.map I am using _.each()

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer you can use `_.filter` instead of where, you justhave to define a filter function instead of using a key map

Answer (score 0):

Concept of `each` function in `lodash` is the same as in `jquery` e.g.

I noticed that your array consist of one element that contains only one field(`enterprise`) therefore you can optimise your iterations:

```
_.each(yourArray[0].enterprise, function(data) {
    console.log(data.id);
});
```